# Azure DevOps - Condition / Expression that allow me to skip the a task inside of a stage

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm currently built a project that allowed me to do some semantic versioning for the git tags as soon as we have a pull request description. However, I would like to know how to build a condition or if statement that allow me to skip the git versioning if we don't have a pull request to make sure we don't create tags when we are running test scenarios.

My code is here (stage):

```
# Creates tag on repo by branch name and build id
  - stage: Creating_Git_Tag
    jobs:
    - job: CalculateVersion
      displayName: Semantic versioning
      steps:
      # Checkout with persist credentials
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

         # Install GitVersion
        - task: gitversion/setup@0
          displayName: Install GitVersion
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '5.x'

        # Retrieve Pull Request Description
        - task: PullRequestDescription@0
          name: RetrievePullRequestDescription
          displayName: Retrieve Pull Request description
          inputs:
            action: 'view'
            outputVariable: 'PullRequest.DescriptionContent'
            isOutput: true
            stripIdentifiers: false

        # Add git commit message that will be picked up by GitVersion ("+semver: patch/minor/major")
        # Depending on the Pull Request description, where the developer has marked the type of change
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: Add git commit message for SemVer
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: |
              Write-Host "Configuring git author info.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            
              git config user.email "user.detals@details.com"
              git config user.name "user.details"
              Write-Host "Doing git checkout..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git checkout -b $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
              Write-Host "Checking Pull Request description..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              $PRdesc = "$(RetrievePullRequestDescription.PullRequest.DescriptionContent)"
              if ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bFix\b)') {
                Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'patch' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                git commit -a -m "+semver: patch [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
              } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bMinor\b)') {
                Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'minor' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
              } elseif ($PRdesc -match '(\[x\] \bMajor\b)') {
                Write-Host "Adding git (empty) commit message to mark this branch as a 'major' SemVer increment." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                git commit -a -m "+semver: major [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
              } else {
                Write-Host "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]Please select the type of change in the Pull Request description, and Re-queue the validation." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                $PRdesc
                exit 1
              }
              Write-Host "Doing git push.." -ForegroundColor Cyan
              git push --set-upstream origin $("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)".replace('refs/heads/', ''))
              Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            
        # Determine the semantic version & test * Tes
        - task: gitversion/execute@0
          displayName: Determine SemVer
```

Does anyone knows how to run an if statement for this, or how can I do it? Do you have an example that I can follow or I guide that I must follow?

Answer (score 1):

you can add below condition to any of you task/step/script which you want to run if the pipeline run is for a pull request, otherwise it will be skipped.

```yaml
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Pull request check
      condition: ne(variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId'],'')
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
             echo "Executing as this run is for a pull request"
```